# SharePoint Advanced troubleshooting - books, blogs?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Are there any good books/blogs to learn Advanced troubleshooting in SharePoint administration 2013

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to go through the pluralsight videos for SharePoint 2013 they really have good content and also refer MSDN or general blogs in the internet when you need them during problems.

Also, if you have MSDN subscription then they generally give 3 months/1 year free subscription.

Answer (score 1):

It's primarily opinion-based question. Meanwhile, I agree with @kesava, I will try to list some of the links that may help you.

**Videos**

- List of Troubleshooting Sharepoint at [Microsoft Virtual Academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/search/SearchResults.aspx#!q=troubleshooting%20sharepoint&lang=1033).
- [Pluralsight: SharePoint Server 2013 Monitoring and Troubleshooting](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/sharepoint-server-2013-monitoring-troubleshooting)
- [Module 8, Troubleshooting & Advanced Administration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZUlQQzUchs)

**Books**

- [SharePoint 2013 Unleashed](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672337339)
- [Deploying SharePoint 2016: Best Practices for Installing, Configuring, and Maintaining SharePoint Server 2016](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1484219988)

**MSDN**

- [Solving problems and troubleshooting in SharePoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748639.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

**Blogs**

- [The SharePoint Farm](https://thesharepointfarm.com/)
- [SharePoint 2013 Troubleshooting Guide](http://info.summit7systems.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-troubleshooting-guide)
- [SharePoint Errors & Problems blog](https://blog.devoworx.net/)